# Unresolved reference in Kotlin - LocationListener - onLocationChanged

Tags: android, kotlin, locationlistener

I got an error message: **Unresolved reference: mListener**
from my code below:
I want to stop `locationupdates` once I got the first fix. Would you please help how to resolve it?

```
var mManager = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
var mListener = object : LocationListener {
    override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
        doSomeWork()
        mManager.removeUpdates(mListener)
    }

    override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String?, status: Int, extras: Bundle?) {

    }

    override fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String?) {

    }

    override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String?) {

    }
}
mManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0f, mListener)
```

Comment: I think you meant to write `mManager.removeUpdates(this)`?

Comment: Thanks, it's solved with your suggestion.